# Не могу заставить работать closures

Tags: ios, swift

Прочитал и попробовал документацию, все понятно, но на практике не так.
Задача: вычесть из одного числа другое с помощью closures.

```
@IBAction func buttonLikePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    calculateLikes(50, newLikes: 1, operation:{$0 - $1})
}

func calculateLikes(currentLikes:Int, newLikes: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int  {
    return operation (currentLikes, newLikes)
}
```

Посмотрел в отладчике, строка

```
calculateLikes(50, newLikes: 1, operation:{$0 - $1})
```

вызывается, но что делает, не ясно. Результат работы функции = 50, а не 49, как ожидалось.

Comment: может все таки без closures? `return currentLikes-newLikes`

Comment: а мне надо по условию использовать closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> вызывается, но что делает, не ясно

Для понимания что происходит распишите полную форму:

```
@IBAction func buttonLikePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print(calculateLikes(50, newLikes: 1, operation: operation))
}

func calculateLikes(currentLikes:Int, newLikes: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int  {
    return operation(currentLikes, newLikes)
}

func operation(currentLikes: Int, newLikes: Int) -> Int {
    return (currentLikes - newLikes)
}
```

Вы передаете в calculateLikes 2 аргумента и функцию, получаете результат работы переданной функции с переданными аргументами и возвращаете его.

А по Вашей записи - все должно работать.